# How to calculate the near neighbour for high-dimensional data(especially for 15000 dims data)?

Tags: distance

How to calculate the near neigbours for high-dimensional data(especially for 15000 dims data)?

----I was confirmed that euclidean distance is not an efficient way to represent the distance between high dimensional datas. Are there any better ideas to calculate the distance for high-dim data?

Comment: How are you representing this data? What (mathematical) structures are you using?

Comment: @Dai The data is represented as a 15000*500 metrix,comprised of 500 samples and 15000 dims feature for each sample